# I want to play two videos embed from YouTube with one play/pause button how can i achieve this

Tags: button, video, youtube, playback

I have a page in my wordpress website where i want to play two youtube videos side by side with one play / pause button. when click on play both videos need to start playing and when pause both need to pause at once. how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome aboard.

### tl;dr

You can achieve this by using YouTube's [YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). Basically, all you need to know is in there. I've taken the liberty and developed a basic test code for what you had in mind. [You can find it here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference):

> https://codepen.io/thaikolja/pen/rNjmLxN

---

### How To Do

If you're interested more, here's - briefly explained - the step-by-step guide. we start with **JavaScript**.

1. Pick a number, let's say three, of random YT video IDs (.e.g. [dQw4w9WgXcQ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)).
2. Add them into an array, just like I've done here:

```
let videoIds = [
    'mM0nhQwN5iU',
    '411r5LekD4M',
    'GxH5piakaHc'
]
```

3. Next, define a `let players = []` array. This is where we'll store the fully functional YouTube objects in the next step.
4. Now comes a Google function that - simply put - turns our YT ID into an object that will be used to turn into an `<iframe>` that we later need to include in our HTML code:

```
/**
 * Created <iframe> players as used with YouTube embeds.
 * Since this is an internal YouTube API function,
 * DO NOT rename it.
 */
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    let player

    /** We loop through the YouTube video IDs */
    for (let videoId of videoIds) {
        player = new YT.Player('player-' + videoId, {
            width:   '100%',
            videoId: videoId
        })

        /** Let's add the newly created player object into our `players` array for later use */
        players.push(player)
    }
}
```

Small but important note: The function name `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` [must remain exactly like this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#july-19,-2012).

When it comes to JS, the last thing we need to do is define the "start all videos" and "stop all videos" button. Here we go:

```
/**
 * Stops to starts all videos defined
 * in `videoIds` (if they're running)
 */
function pauseAllVideos() {
    for (let i in players) {
        players[i].pauseVideo()
    }
}

/**
 * Function to starts all videos as specified
 * in `videoIds`.
 */
function playAllVideos() {
    for (let i in players) {
        players[i].playVideo()
    }
}
```

The last part is the HTML mockup. I've used Bootstrap 4.6 (CSS only) to make it look a little neater, but it'd also work without. Here's the source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Play and Pause all YouToube Videos at Once</title>
        <script src="./main.js"></script>
        <!-- This is just Bootstrap 5.0 for styling purposes and is optional -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Bootstrap icons, to make it look a bit nicer -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
        <style>
            i {
                margin-right: 5px;
            }

            .player {
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container my-5">
            <div class="row mb-5">
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 mb-3 mb-lg-0">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success w-100 text-center" onclick="playAllVideos()">
                        <i class="bi-play-circle-fill"></i>
                        Play all Videos
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger w-100" onclick="pauseAllVideos()">
                        <i class="bi-stop-circle-fill"></i>
                        Play all Videos
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="row">
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            /** We create n elements of players, based on the YouTube IDs entered in `main.js` */
                            for (let videoId of videoIds) {
                                document.write(
                                    '<div class="player" id="player-' + videoId + '"></div>'
                                )
                            }
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Don't forget the main library from YouTube - otherwise it won't work, obviously -->
        <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api" defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this was of any help.

Cheers!